# iPhone: prevent the access to some domains if I am not connected to VPN

Tags: iphone, ios, network, vpn

My iPhone is connected to the WiFi of the company I am working in. My VPN is almost always activated so I hope that the domain names I visit are hidden to my employer.

Sometimes, the VPN is not activated:

- The morning if I forget to activate it
- At some occasions, if I am disconnected from the server by a technical issue

At that very moment the VPN is not activated, is it possible *to prevent my iPhone to access specific domain names*?

Edit: or maybe there are alternative solutions, based on Tor/Brave browser which would hide the visited domain names or DNS-over-HTTPS implementations?

Comment: If you're visiting sites on a company device you don't want your company to know about, perhaps you shouldn't use that device.